# Android Emulator has no window frame

Tags: android, android-emulator

[image]

I'm new to android developing and have an issue with android emulator, it has no window frame! I can't move it over my screen or move to second monitor, it is freaking me out! I tried to google it out, but found no solution, can anyone tell me how can I fix that?

[image: setting of avd]

Comment: Your screen show doesn't show the Windows taskbar, do you keep that hidden normally?

Comment: @krislarson I'm sorry, didn't think that it may be confusing, checkout updated screenshot please, on the left side is my second monitor

Comment: I'm deleting my answer, because I had an issue like yours, but it was a different flavor.  Windows put the title bar beyond the top of the screen, and I just moved the taskbar from the bottom to the side and voila.  From your AVD screenshot I see you're using Eclipse.  The AVD Manager for Eclipse sucks.  I've started transitioning over to Android Studio, it's a little better.  If you haven't already, I would recommend you check out Genymotion.  They do Android emulation with VirtualBox, much better than QEMU.  A lot easier to work with.

Comment: @krislarson thanks for advice, I'll try to use Genymotion then

Comment: If you've ever used VirtualBox, you know you can resize the display on the fly and the display will scale to match.  It works like that in Genymotion too.

Answer (score 12):

I had same problem.  There is a frame.  It just launches outside the screen and you can't grab it.

"Simple" solution:  Start the emulator and then right click on the Windows taskbar and hit "Cascade Windows".  That will move the emulator window down low enough to grab the Windows frame.

Comment: works perfectly but you need to click the windows clock not the taskbar itself :)

Answer (score 9):

There is a nice workaround: open the window context menu by pressing alt+space. Then select 'move' and move the window with the arrow keys.

Answer (score 1):

just go to Android device manager and edit your device, uncheck the device frame checkbox, and it will solve your problem.