# Android AVD Google APIs Intel x86 versus ARM EABI

Tags: android

Hello dear Android Developers (Developers, Developers),
It's not a real question, its more my experience with these AVDs.

Im using a Windows PC with 4GB RAM, Android Studio 1.1. I liked to setup two different AVD's, one for Nexus 5 and one for Nexus 4. All fine with ARM EABI v7a System Image, and also with Google APIs.

Then I tried the Google APIs Intel x86 Atom Image (made the setting in BIOS, and told Intel to use 1536MB RAM).
Well, the Nexus 4 works, but Nexus 5 will never run! And additionally: I dont experience much of a difference in speed in comparision to ARM!

The only good thing with Intel: The AVD works as a seperate window, which I can move, while else the AVDs are "docked" on top of my monitor without the possibility to move it.

I just wonder why I experience no speed difference (feeled), because I read somewhere its up to 10 times faster? And why Nexus 5 (with standard data (1536MB RAM, Use Host GPU and enable keyboard input)) doesnt work at all, while Nexus 4 does. (The only difference I see on those both is the resolution)

Thanks much in forward (for suggests)
Martin

Comment: Try Genymotion. You will never regret for this choice :)

Comment: Sorry for off topic comment

Comment: I took a look at Genymotion already, but they suggest very high RAM, which I cant handle with my 4GB, I fear.

Comment: Can not say anything. You might try lower it and see if it is still useful

Comment: the Nexus 5 AVD might not satisfy the minimum requirement to run on your PC. Try configuring the AVD with Double the minimum requirement which will hopefully will resolve your problem.

Comment: Since I run the AVD permanently while developing (because starting time is very long), I wonder if the AVD cuts my RAM all the time. If yes, I would prefer not to give more than 1536MB.

Comment: Concerning the "docked" AVDs, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29222522/android-emulator-has-no-window-frame/29430872#29430872